# Automatically lock screen of Chromebook when lid is closed

Tags: laptop, security, google-chrome-os, suspend, chromebook

Can a Chromebook be configured to automatically lock the screen when I close the lid?

There is a discussion in [If someone steals my chromebook while it's off, will him be able to see my cached data?](https://superuser.com/questions/295966/if-someone-steals-my-chromebook-while-its-off-will-him-be-able-to-see-my-cache) about the security of user data for a Chromebook which has been shutdown, but I am trying to ensure user data is secure when the laptop is **suspended** by closing the lid. My device is a Samsung Series 5 running (obviously!) the latest version of ChromeOS. I've noticed that the default configuration has the laptop resuming with no password prompt after being suspended.

On a Chromium support page ([Protecting Cached User Data](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/protecting-cached-user-data)), the following is mentioned as a risk which allows the encryption mechanism to be bypassed:

> An attacker will be able to access all user data if the machine is
>   suspended or logged in and screen locking is disabled.

I haven't been able to find more details yet on how to enable "screen locking".

Please note that I know there is a "lock" menu item I could select before closing the lid but I'm really trying to keep with what I believe is the spirit of the Chrome OS experience by minimizing any extra steps that stand between me and my personal computing. I want locking to "just work" (but of course I am willing to take the extra step of typing my password when I resume from suspend).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get this option by following these steps:

1. Sign in to your Chrome device.
2. Click the status area in the lower-right corner, where your account picture appears.
3. Select Settings and Help and find the "People" section.
4. Use the "Require password to wake from sleep" check box to adjust this setting.

Now each time your Chromebook goes to 'sleep' you will need a password at the lock screem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution as of v91.0.

1. Open the **Chromebook Settings** by clicking on the clock in the lower right and then the gear icon on the top of menu.
2. Click on **Security and Privacy** on the left menu and then select **Lock screen and sign-in**.
3. **Confirm** in your password.
4. Enable **show lock screen when waking up from sleep**.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible; see feature request https://crbug.com/902589 (restricted access, sorry) for a power option "Lock when cover is closed".

Workaround: select both options "Sleep when cover is closed" and "Show lock screen when waking up from sleep".